# Move files from a directory while ignoring the currently opened file

Tags: java

I have a java program which, among other things, writes to a timestamped (SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmm")) log file. Each time the program is run, it moves any log files currently in the folder to a different folder, while writing to a new log file.

My (minor) problem is that as well as the old log files, it attempts to move the log file that I'm currently writing to, which is caught in an exception, then it continues with the rest of the program. This doesn't affect the program's duties as it skips over this attempt, but this exception does show in the log file, which isn't really what one would want.

Is there a way to copy a load of files of one type, while ignoring the file that's currently being written to?

The code:

```
try {

...

    Path logDir = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath( logTrim );
    String tempLogDir = logTrim + "\\" + logDirName1 + "\\" + logDirName2 + "\\";
    DirectoryStream<Path> logStream = Files.newDirectoryStream( logDir, "lol*log" );
    for (Path path : logStream) {
        Path logDir2 = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath( tempLogDir + "\\" + path.getFileName().toString() );
        Files.move(path, logDir2, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, path.getFileName() + " moved to " + logDirName1 + "\n");
    }
    logStream.close();
}

catch (Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

The error I don't like:

```
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: \\..\..\lol20150320_1522.log -> \\..\..\lol20150320_1522.log: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Many thanks all

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right one solution is to rename the log file you are writing atm and check the names of the files you are moving.  Another option is to check the time information in the filename if it is an old log file. Last but not least a dirty hack is to use a catch block without any exception handling in your loop.